# Parameter estimation (Uniform Distribution)- Urgent Help Needed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

I want to estimate a parameter $k$, from my data $(y_1,y_2, ....,y_n)$ which are independent and identically distributed.

$k=a$, $\;$$\;$$\;$$\;$$\;$$\;$ if $y_i$ is uniformly distributed on $[a,b]$ or $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$$\;$ $\;$

$k=a+1$, $\;$ if $y_i$ is uniformly distributed on $[a+1, b+1]$.

My question is this: What are the problems of estimation and inference in my model? The discussions I have seen so far do not answer my question

Note: I must consider at least 2 different consistent estimators of $k$

Thanks.

Comment: Huh?  why repeat yourself with a $+1$?

Comment: it's not a repetition. k takes each of those values depending on the known distribution of Y. But you'll notice the overlap in the two possible distributions of Y, hence the question about the possible problems with the estimation / inference